# Add background color to section header dynamically in UITableView iOS 5

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uicolor, sectionheader

I have added custom section header for Plain UITableView in my app. While scrolling my cells goes behind section header. I want section header to be displayed on screen till section doesn't change. Till now my app works as per my requirement.

What I want is , when table cell goes behind my section header , I want to change the background color of the section header & change the text color of section title, so that user can clearly see the cells contents.

How can I implement above functionality ? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you returning your "custom section header" for your UITableView?

If you have a delegate set for your UITableView, you can return your custom section header via the delegate's [`tableView: viewForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a) method, where you can return any UIView you want (e.g. a UILabel, where you control the font color ***and*** the background color). I've linked Apple's documentation for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using same delegate method. Also I am returning UILabel from above method. But I want background color & text color for UILabel changes only when section header covers my cell. Meaning when my cell goes behind my section header.